# Azure Storage: Deploy Queue via ARM template

Tags: deployment, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-storage-queues

Is there a way to deploy Queues within a Storage Account via ARM templates? Haven't found an option so far.

If yes, how?
If not, is it planned to provide this capability?
If not and not planned, which approach do you recommend for automated deployments?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to deploy Queues within a Storage Account via ARM templates?

**No, it's not support now**.

ARM templates could deploy Azure Storage accounts, blob container, **but not support to deploy queues, or tables within storage account**. 
Here is a link to a sample template to create a container: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/101-storage-blob-container/

You can vote up your voice to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/9306108-let-me-define-preconfigured-blob-containers-table) to promote the further achieved.

Answer (score 2):

A few ways you can think about data plane operations in deployment/apps

1) the code that consumes the queue can create on init if it doesn't exist

2) if you're deploying via a pipeline, use a pipeline task to perform data plane operations

3) in a template use the [deploymentScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template?tabs=CLI) resource to create it - this is a bit heavyweight for the task you need, but it will work.

That help?